# Pair transactions into date range rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table structured like below, that shows when employees are added (operation=I) or removed (operation=D) from an account as a particular role

```
Account | Employee | Role | Operation | OperationTimestamp
ABC     | 1        | Rep  | I         | 1/1/2018
DEF     | 1        | Mgr  | I         | 1/1/2018
ABC     | 1        | Rep  | D         | 3/31/2018
ABC     | 1        | Rep  | I         | 7/1/2018
ABC     | 1        | Rep  | D         | 12/31/2018
ABC     | 2        | Mgr  | I         | 1/1/2018
DEF     | 2        | Exc  | I         | 1/1/2018
ABC     | 2        | Mgr  | D         | 3/31/2018
ABC     | 2        | Mgr  | I         | 6/1/2018
ABC     | 2        | Mgr  | D         | 10/31/2018
```

(I = Insert, D = Delete)

I need to develop a query that would return the account, employee, role and date range that the employee was on that account like so:

```
Account | Employee | Role | StartingDate | EndingDate
ABC     | 1        | Rep  | 1/1/2018     | 3/31/2018
DEF     | 1        | Mgr  | 1/1/2018     | NULL
ABC     | 1        | Rep  | 7/1/2018     | 12/31/2018
ABC     | 2        | Mgr  | 1/1/2018     | 3/31/2018
DEF     | 2        | Exc  | 1/1/2018     | NULL
ABC     | 2        | Mgr  | 6/1/2018     | 10/31/2018
```

So as you can see from the result set, if an employee is added to an account, but has not been removed, then then EndingDate should be `NULL`.

Where I'm struggling is that you can have the same employee added/removed from an account multiple times and/or in multiple roles. My guts says I need to order the transactions by account>employee>role>date and somehow group every 2 lines together (since it should always be an I operation, followed by a D operation) but I'm not sure how to handle the "missing" deletes if they're still on an account.

Comment: for a given role, can there be more than one consecutive I or is I always followed by D?

Comment: Gordon's now deleted answer is correct, and this indeed is gaps and islands problem.  [Here is a DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac3060a760f97977a86cffc84f4908f7) which you all may use to test your queries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Unless they want something more than stated in the question I think this is much simpler than a Gaps and Islands problem.  It is simply finding the single `D` record that follows an `I` record for each `Account | Employee | Role` combination.

Comment: Yes but how do you do that?

Comment: Well...I was going to say that it's safe to assume a D follows an I for the same account/emp/role, but I've now found some bizarre ones where there are D's with no original I's. I believe this occurred during a database migration (no I's when the employee was originally put on the account because they were attached to the account as part of the migration) but then the first time they were taken off, a D transaction appears. So I may have a more complicated scenario to address. Not thrilled....

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**: An `I` operation is never followed by another `I` for the same combination (account, employee, role); if there is a next row (it may not be for that combination) it's always a `D`.

Data:

```
create table my_table (
  Account varchar(3), 
  Employee int, 
  role varchar(3),
  Operation varchar(1),
  OperationTimestamp datetime
);

insert into my_table values
 ('ABC',1,'Rep','I','20180101')
,('DEF',1,'Mgr','I','20180101')
,('ABC',1,'Rep','D','20180331')
,('ABC',1,'Rep','I','20180701')
,('ABC',1,'Rep','D','20181231')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','I','20180101')
,('DEF',2,'Exc','I','20180101')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','D','20180331')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','I','20180601')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','D','20181031');
```

If the above is true, then I would use the following query:

```
with
x as (
  select
    account, employee, role, operationtimestamp, operation,
    lead(operation) 
      over(partition by account, employee, role
           order by account, employee, role, operationtimestamp)
      as next_op,
    lead(operationtimestamp)
      over(partition by account, employee, role
           order by account, employee, role, operationtimestamp)
      as next_ts
  from my_table
),
y as(
  select
    account, employee, role,
    operationtimestamp as startingdate,
    next_ts as endingdate
  from x
  where operation = 'I'
)
select *
from y
order by employee, startingdate
```

Result:

```
account  employee  role  startingdate           endingdate           
-------  --------  ----  ---------------------  ---------------------
ABC      1         Rep   2018-01-01 00:00:00.0  2018-03-31 00:00:00.0
DEF      1         Mgr   2018-01-01 00:00:00.0  <null>               
ABC      1         Rep   2018-07-01 00:00:00.0  2018-12-31 00:00:00.0
ABC      2         Mgr   2018-01-01 00:00:00.0  2018-03-31 00:00:00.0
DEF      2         Exc   2018-01-01 00:00:00.0  <null>               
ABC      2         Mgr   2018-06-01 00:00:00.0  2018-10-31 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: You do not need your `y` `cte` there.  Just put the `order by` at the end of the second statement

Comment: I don't have a great test environment so do you have any idea how LEAD() performs compared to the LEFT JOIN in @iamdave's answer?

Comment: I tend to think that `LEAD()` is performed by "sort" operation while a left join is performed by a NLS (or a hash join, or a merge join). I would say the sort operation should be faster. To find out for real you would need to retrieve the execution plan for both queries and compare them. The SQL optimizer sometimes gets it right, while other times is not that great. Anyway, compare the cost of both plans.

Comment: So apparently even though we're on SQL2014, the compatibility level is set to 100 (not 110 or higher) so I can't use LEAD(). I'm looking into if we can change it or not. That may affect which answer I select, but I do like your answer as it makes the most sense to me

Answer (score 1):

With a `row_number` and a self `join` this is fairly straightforward:

```
declare @t table(Account varchar(3), Employee int, EmpRole varchar(3), Operation varchar(1), OperationTimestamp datetime);
insert into @t values
 ('ABC',1,'Rep','I','20180101')
,('DEF',1,'Mgr','I','20180101')
,('ABC',1,'Rep','D','20180331')
,('ABC',1,'Rep','I','20180701')
,('ABC',1,'Rep','D','20181231')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','I','20180101')
,('DEF',2,'Exc','I','20180101')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','D','20180331')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','I','20180601')
,('ABC',2,'Mgr','D','20181031');

with d as
(
    select Account
            ,Employee
            ,EmpRole
            ,Operation
            ,OperationTimestamp
            ,row_number() over (partition by Account, Employee, EmpRole order by OperationTimestamp) as ord
    from @t
)
select s.Account
    ,s.Employee
    ,s.EmpRole
    ,s.OperationTimestamp as OperationTimestampStart
    ,e.OperationTimestamp as OperationTimestampEnd
from d as s
    left join d as e
        on s.Account = e.Account
            and s.Employee = e.Employee
            and s.EmpRole = e.EmpRole
            and s.ord = e.ord-1
where s.Operation = 'I';
```

## Output

```
+---------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| Account | Employee | EmpRole | OperationTimestampStart | OperationTimestampEnd |
+---------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| ABC     |        1 | Rep     | 2018-01-01              | 2018-03-31            |
| ABC     |        1 | Rep     | 2018-07-01              | 2018-12-31            |
| ABC     |        2 | Mgr     | 2018-01-01              | 2018-03-31            |
| ABC     |        2 | Mgr     | 2018-06-01              | 2018-10-31            |
| DEF     |        1 | Mgr     | 2018-01-01              | NULL                  |
| DEF     |        2 | Exc     | 2018-01-01              | NULL                  |
+---------+----------+---------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `lead()` or a cumulative `min()`.  Here is what I mean:

```
select account, employee, role, OperationTimestamp, EndingDate
from (select t.*,
             min(case when operation = 'D' then OperationTimestamp end) over
                 (partition by account, employee, role
                  order by OperationTimestamp desc
                 ) as EndingDate
      from t
     ) t
where operation = 'I';
```